# java check for admin rights on a specific location

Tags: java, file-io, installation

I am developing an application which installs an exe file on a particular directory on either local or remote using java. Is there anyway to check whether that remote location has admin rights or is that an installable location using java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out the user/session privileges or the destination (folder) privileges?  I know of some (quirky) ways to determine if the location is writable...

Comment: yes i am looking on the destination folder privileges to check if it is installable.

Comment: which operation system you are using ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are better ways to achieve this in Java 7, check out [File I/O (Featuring NIO.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) for more details (in particular [Checking a File or Directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html), but I don't (yet) have experience with this API.

Under Java 6 and below we had to do some hoop jumping (especially under Windows 7 and UAC)...

You can use `File#canWrite` to check to see if the destination path is writable, this will, how ever, return `true` under Windows 7, even when the UAC won't let you...much to our horror...

We wrote a simple utility method that basically checks `File#canWrite`, if it was true, it wrote a temp file, with a simple String and checked to see if it existed (`File#exists`) and that the contents was what we wrote was the same.  If that worked, then were sure we could write to the location...

(Note the paranoia, we spent 2 weeks running tests to find the problem and come up with a solution we could trust)